# Collapsible Table Rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am looking for a way to make table rows collasible or expandable in multiple levels.
The default view should be collapsed (maybe its possible to show level 0 and 1?)

This is what i have right now, gathered from an answer on another question on here.

```
<table>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
         </tr>
      <tr class="level_0" id="10">
        <td>10</td>
        <td> Level 0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="level_1 parent_10" id="11">
        <td>10.1</td>
        <td>Level 1</td>
      </tr>
     <tr class="level_1 parent_10" id="12">
        <td >10.2</td>
        <td>Level 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="level_2 parent_12" id="13">
        <td>10.2.1</td>
        <td>Level 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="level_0" id="20">
        <td>20</td>
        <td> Level 0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="level_1 parent_20" id="21">
        <td>20.1</td>
        <td>Level 1</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') throw "jQuery Required";

jQuery(function ($) {
    var treeTable = {
        parentClassPrefix : '',
        collapsedClass : 'collapsed',
        init : function(parentClassPrefix) {
            this.parentClassPrefix = parentClassPrefix;
            $('table').on('click', 'tr', function () { 
                treeTable.toggleRowChildren($(this));
            });
        },
        toggleRowChildren : function(parentRow) {
            var childClass = this.parentClassPrefix+parentRow.attr('id');
            var childrenRows = $('tr', parentRow.parent()).filter('.'+childClass);
            childrenRows.toggle();
            childrenRows.each(function(){
                if (!$(this).hasClass(treeTable.collapsedClass)) {
                    treeTable.toggleRowChildren($(this));
                }
            });
            parentRow.toggleClass(this.collapsedClass);
        }
    };

    treeTable.init('parent_');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this - this could be done better if I was going to take little more time looking at it. But this is just a quick example of how it could be done.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".level_0").each(function()
  {
    console.log("IN HERE");
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.level_0').toggle();
  });
  
});

$(document).on("click", '.level_0', function()
{
  $(this).nextUntil('tr.level_0').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><table>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
         </tr>
      <tr class="level_0" id="10">
        <td>10</td>
        <td> Level 0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="level_1 parent_10" id="11">
        <td>10.1</td>
        <td>Level 1</td>
      </tr>
     <tr class="level_1 parent_10" id="12">
        <td >10.2</td>
        <td>Level 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="level_2 parent_12" id="13">
        <td>10.2.1</td>
        <td>Level 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="level_0" id="20">
        <td>20</td>
        <td> Level 0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="level_1 parent_20" id="21">
        <td>20.1</td>
        <td>Level 1</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately this is not working for me.
I need the default view to be collapsed and level_0 (better level 0 and level 1).
Your solution is collapsing on click and it acutally only collapses to level 1 if there is no level 2 :-(

Comment: @Markus Try my updated answer, it may be because of the `.click` instead of `.on`

Comment: Still not working. If you run your own code snippet, you'll see the same behaviour i have described.

Comment: @Markus I've just tried my code snippet and it collapses each `tr` when you click on the higher level `tr` so if you click `level_0` it'll collapse `level_1` and when you click `level_1` it'll collapse `level_2`

Comment: You are right. Let me rephrase my issue: When you click `level_0` it should collapse `level_1` and `level_2` at the same time. And by default everything should be collapsed.

Comment: Thanks alot! Almost Perfect :-)
How would i achieve the on click level_0 > expand level_1 and on click level_1 > expand level_2.
While on click level_0 would collapse all children. And on click level_1 would collapse all level_2 childen.